# How do I upgrade from ubuntu 9.10 to 12.10 on my Acer Aspire 3000

Tags: installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

I had my Acer Aspire 3000 as a dual boot XP/ubuntu 9.10 a couple years ago. I recently blew the dust of it and wanted to upgrade to 7/Ubuntu 12.10 so I began by formatting the Ubuntu side of the partition and apparently damaged the mbr as I could only get black screen with the error message:

```
GRUB loading...
error: no such partition
grub rescue>
```

I then slaved the hdd to my win7 desktop and formatted the entire drive, both sides of the partition then reinstalled it in the Acer and tried to install win7. Upon starting the Acer I got the same error message:

```
GRUB loading...
error: no such partition
grub rescue>
```

I then tried to reinstall Ubuntu 9.10 as I have an Ubuntu produced installation cd. Same result.

Next day I received a new battery I had ordered for the Acer. I plugged it and the power supply in and hit the power button just to see if I at least could charge the battery but to my surprise Ubuntu 9.10 began to install, so I let it and it did. Now the hard drive shows 58 gb and 2.5gb partitions neither of which is formatted NTFS for/by windows. I am guessing that the GRUB/mbr was repaired somehow by the Ubuntu reinstallation.

My question, should you choose to accept it;
How can I get to my goal of dual boot win7/Ubuntu 12.10. I am a beginner and don't know much about linux or the terminology. Thank you for your thoughts and help.

Comment: May I ask, why do you install Ubuntu 9.10 (which is no longer supported), when you actually want 12.10? Why not install W7 on to a clean hdd, and then install whatever version of Ubuntu you wish to use?

Answer (score 2):

the deal is, you don't upgrade it 9.10 to 12.10 because you can't. You have do this long way instead:

9.10 --> 10.04 --> 12.04 --> 12.10

of course it's MUCH easier to make a fresh install of 12.10

install windows 7 first then install 12.10 is the easiest and fastest way to get your dual boot setup.

Comment: I tried to install win7 first but failed several times. I had given up and was going to take my Acer to someone more qualified. When I turned the machine on to charge the battery I had forgotten that the Ubuntu disk was still in the drive from earlier when I had tried to use it to undo the damage to the GRUB/mbr. It appears that at least that was ultimately successful. Now I am hesitant to delete Ubuntu again for fear of repeating the disaster I narrowly escaped. How can I wipe the drive and prepare it for win 7 with out again damaging the GRUB/mbr?

Comment: You should be fine with installing Windows 7 on the whole HDD. But before you do make a CD/DVD of Ubuntu 12.04 or 12.10. So if this doesn't work you will at least be able to install Ubuntu. Good luck, report back what you get!

Comment: And the proper method of removing Ubuntu is?

Comment: Reinstalling Windows should remove Ubuntu.

Comment: @770 you don't remove Ubuntu, you make a fresh install of the whole HDD, I mean you format the drive and then install Windows, you can do this in the Windows installer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Acer Aspire 3000 has only 256 mb of memory. Unless you have upgraded it you are not going to be able to load neither Windows 7, nor Ubuntu 12.04 on it. Both need way more memory.

In my experience Windows 7 needs at least 2Gb to run smoothly and Ubuntu 12.04 at least 1 Gb. Both will refuse to install with only 256 Mb.

You should be able to install [Lubuntu](http://www.lubuntu.net/), a lighter version of Ubuntu, 12.04 on it and make it usable, but even them you will be short of RAM. Expect it to be more bare-bones and have more rough edges than core Ubuntu.

Comment: I have  recently installed 2g of memory so I should be good there. The tag on the Acer says "Vista Capable" so I suspect it should handle 7 with the memory upgrade

Comment: If it won't I can always reload XP. I have seen many other posts from people who have had the same trouble deleting Ubuntu and I'd like to avoid that. Did I go about it incorrectly?

Comment: Yes, with 2 Gb of memory both Ubuntu and 7 should work.

Comment: Question is, how should I go about this to avoid the GRUB error issue again?

Comment: Thank you all for your input. I found my solution on another thread: http://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on

Comment: Nice. I'm voting to close this question then.